# Program to optimize cost

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

This is my problem set for one of my CS class and I am kind of stuck. Here is the summary of the problem.

```
Create a program that will:
1) take a list of grocery stores and its available items and prices
2) take a list of required items that you need to buy
3) output a supermarket where you can get all your items with the cheapest price

input: supermarkets.list, [tomato, orange, turnip]
output: supermarket_1

The list looks something like
supermarket_1
$2.00 tomato
$3.00 orange
$4.00 tomato, orange, turnip

supermarket_2
$3.00 tomato
$2.00 orange
$3.00 turnip
$15.00 tomato, orange, turnip

If we want to buy tomato and orange, then the optimal solution would be buying 
from supermarket_1 $4.00. Note that it is possible for an item to be bough 
twice. So if wanted to buy 2 tomatoes, buying from supermarket_1 would be the 
optimal solution.
```

So far, I have been able to put the dataset into a data structure that I hope will allow me to easily do operations on it. I basically have a dictionary of supermarkets and the value would point to a another dictionary containing the mapping from each entry to its price.

```
supermarket_1 --> [turnip --> $2.00]
                  [orange --> $1.50]
```

One way is to use brute force, to get all combinations and find whichever satisfies the solution and find the one with the minimum. So far, this is what I can come up with. **There is no assumption that the price of a combination of two items would be less than buying each separately.**

Any suggestions hints are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the optimal solution for a specific supermarket is a generalization of the [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), which is NP-complete. The reduction goes as follows:
Given an instance of the set cover problem, just define a cost function assigning 1 to each combination, apply an algorithm that solves your problem, and you obtain an optimal solution of the set cover instance. (Finding the minimal price hence corresponds to finding the minimum number of covering sets.) Thus, your Problem is [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), and you cannot expect to finde a solution that runs in polynomial time.

You really should implement the brute-force method you mentioned. I too recommand you to do this as a first step. If the performance is not sufficient, you can try a 
using a MIP-formulation and a solver like CPLEX, or you have to devolop a heuristic approach.

For a single supermarket, it is rather trivial to find a [mixed integer program (MIP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_linear_programming#Integer_unknowns). Let `x_i` be the integer number how often product combination `i` is contained in a solution, `c_i` its cost and `w_ij` the number how often product `j` is contained in product combination `i`. Then, you are minimizing

```
sum_i x_i * c_i
```

subject to conditions like

```
sum_i x_i * w_ij >= r_j,
```

where `r_j` is the number how often product `j` is required.

Comment: Why 1 for each combination when there is an actual price associated to each item?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have one method, so implement it now so you have something that works to submit.  A brute-force solution should not take long to code up, then you can get some performance data and you can think about the problem more deeply.  Guesstimate the number of supermarkets in a reasonable shopping range in a large city.  Create that many supermarket records and link them to product tables with random-ish prices, (this is more work than the solution).

Run your brute-force solution.  Does it work?  If it outputs a solution, 'manually' add up the prices and list them against three other 'supermarket' records taken at random, (just pick a number), showing that the total is less or equal.  Modify the price of an item on your list so that the solution is no longer cheap and re-run, so that you get a different solution.

Is it so fast that no further work is justified?  If so, say so in the conclusions section of your report and post the lot to your prof/TA.  You understood the task, thought about it, came up with a solution, implemented it, tested it with a representative dataset and so shown that functionality is demonstrable and performance is adequate -  your assignment is over, go to the bar, think about the next one over a beer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "brute force" solution.
Why don't you just calculate the cost of your list of items in each of the supermarkets, and then select the minimum? Complexity would be in O(#items x #supermarkets) which is good.

Regarding your data structure you can also simply have a matrix (2 dimension array) price[super][item], and use ids for your supermarkets/items.

Comment: it would have to be more than O(items*supermarkets) because I can buy multiple items from the same supermarket and I would have to look for the one supermarket that would allow me to get the items that i need with the cheapest price.

Comment: When I say brute force way, I mean finding all possible combinations of items in a supermarket and find the minimum. If I have these items, [[xy],[xz],[xyz]] => [ [[xy],[xz]] , [xyz]]. Both solutions contain the items that I need I just need to find one with the minimum cost. The biggest challenge for me is to get those combinations and to find the optimal algo to get it

Comment: I don't really see why you want to find combinations, it is not like if you had the option to choose which price you will pay right?

Comment: Say you go to the second supermarket, you will necessarily pay $15 (assuming you can't say that you will buy each item separetely as the tuple (tomato, orange, turnip) is defined - this is some quadratic problem).
Assume now that you need an extra tomato, you will have to buy it separately.
In my mind, a possible algorithm is to first select the biggest set of required items from the supermarket, then rest 1 to the required quantities, and iterate.

Comment: My mistake. I don't think I explained the problem correctly. You can only but the items that you need from 1 supermarket. The program is supposed to find the supermarket that has all of the items that I need with the cheapest price. If the items are segregated by supermarkets then there is no solution.